# How can I get the smell out of a Condenser / Heatpump dryer?

Tags: cleaning, home, smell, laundry

I have a [heat pump dryer](https://www.canstarblue.com.au/appliances/heat-pump-dryers/) that's stated to smell a bit kind of a mildew smell I suppose. Because of this, I've taken to ensure that the clothes are out of it almost immediately e.g. no leaving overnight like I used to be able to with a vented dryer.

**Steps I've taken to minimise the smell**

- Take clothes and water out as soon as possible
- Leave the water catchment outside the dryer.
- Tried calling the dryer vendor and did not get any good suggestions.

**What I've considered**

- Dismantling the dryer to clean the internals (Many problems and challenges with this)

**What next**

I'm a little stuck getting the smell out of the dryer, so id love to know a viable solution.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "heatpump dryer" please?

Comment: @Lefty here is a description https://www.canstarblue.com.au/appliances/heat-pump-dryers/.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting approach. I've had the same condensing dryer for about 16 years and never had any problem of the sort you're having. I only clean the condenser about every 2 years as well. Have you had the dryer very long?

Comment: @Lefty  About 6 months, maybe it's a problem that only affects heat pump dryers

Answer (score 1):

If it behaves like a conventional heat pump by extracting the humidity (water) from clothing. The water condensed has to go somewhere. Perhaps it is a drainage issue. Standing water will help mold and mildew grow..hence the smell. This is the first time I have heard of a heat pump dryer so I am just speculating.

Answer (score 1):

I've a Bosch HPC dryer that advertises itself as having a self cleaning condenser, and there isn't a noticeable smell after two years use. 
I'd look at cleaning all easy access areas that moisture builds up first - the condenser unit should be removable for cleaning, as should the water tank. The compartment the condenser sits in would be a prime candidate too. If the dryer is connected via a permanent drain system to the wate water pipes, ensure the trap that prevents sewer smells entering the dryer is working properly

I suspect that HPCs may be more liable to mold growth because they don't run as hot as a standard condenser

Answer (score 1):

I also had a mildewy smell in both my Samsung washing machine and my Samsung heat pump tumble dryer. I have cured it..so far so good.
I take out all the lint every time, and leave the condenser drawer to dry fully out after the load has finished. I then put in 1 tsp of Zoflora or disinfectant to stay in there until next use. I leave the door open. I also used to put in a microfibre cloth with a tsp of zoflora on it and leave that sitting in the drum, but I have now got the wool tumble drier balls and I add a splash of zoflora to those and leave them in the drier. This has worked, I no longer get a fusty smell. Cleaning out the bits you can get too is obviously crucial as well.
The washing machine is pretty much the same, I leave a cloth with zoflora on it in the drum when not in use and take out the drawer to fully dry out.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Bosch Heat Pump Condenser Drier and we've been wondering where this horrible smell is coming from for months.  Today I decided it was the drier.  No obvious way of cleaning it.  It has a self cleaner in it which I see is riddled with drier lint.  I assume that lint has gone into the drier somewhere and needs a clean out.  Perhaps there is a maintenance / service option.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting or renting an ozone generator. This will completely take care of it. Close off the room, run the ozonator for an hour (no plants, animals or people) in the room and that ozone will kill all the icky molds and bacteria making the stink. This totally works!